# node.js web app not responding as it should be

Tags: android, node.js, pusher

I deployed pusher's authentication program code on heroku/virtual server. The server app starts up successfully but when a android mobile client tries to connect the following errors are diplayed on the console -

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'handle' of undefined
at Function.app.handle (~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:122:16)
at Layer.fn [as handle] (~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:189:17)
at trim_prefix (~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:255:15)
at ~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:216:9
at Function.proto.process_params (~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:12)
at next (~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:207:19)
at Layer.expressInit [as handle] (~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:23:5)
at trim_prefix (~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:255:15)
at ~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:216:9
at Function.proto.process_params (~/MessagingServer/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:12)
```

The application does not crash though.

The following output is logged in the logcat for the android app -

```
05-29 08:01:21.960: I/System.out(2531): java.io.FileNotFoundException:     http://192.168.146.128:5000 com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.146.128:5000
```

The source code for the messaging server is here -

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var Pusher = require( 'pusher' );
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser'); 
var app = express( logger() );
app.use( express(bodyParser() ));

var pusher = new Pusher( { appId: '<id>', key:'<key>', secret:'<secret>' } );

app.post( '/pusher/auth', function( req, res ) {
  var socketId = req.body.socket_id;
  var channel = req.body.channel_name;
  var auth = pusher.auth( socketId, channel );
  res.send( auth );
} );

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen( port );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bodyParser middleware isn't attached in the right way, so req.body will be undefined. You should attach your middleware like this:

```
app.use(logger());
app.use(bodyParser());
```